# WordPress: get_post_type_archive_link doesn't work on certain pages

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, shortcode

I'm using the function `get_post_type_archive_link` to get the link of a post type archive which I want to use in a shortcode function.

The code looks like this:

```
$account_help_link = get_post_type_archive_link('questions');
```

It works fine on almost every page but on some archives it doesn't work and outputs the current page/archive URL.

Is there any way to debug that? Or do I need to add some extra code to it?
I've no idea where to look and why it's not working on these pages.

Comment: Can you give us more details about what is happening, e.g. on the pages where it doesn't work, are they all the same post type(s)? What type of page are they / what template are these pages using (e.g. single.php for individual posts, page.php for pages, etc) Are you using custom post types and/or custom template files for the pages that have the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Have you registered your new type of post (in your functions.php or another php file) with the property 'has_archive' set to true?

And have you created a "archive-question.php" file in your theme root?

Something like this:

```html
<?php

function question_post_types()
{
  register_post_type('question', array(
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true, /* this will tell WP to create a route */
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'questions'),
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Questions',
    ),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-comments'
  ));
}

add_action('init', 'question_post_types');
```

[Some help here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/)

Editing this answer after reading your comment:
"Yes to all"

Then, I would suggest you to try this inside your "single-question.php":

```html
<a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link('question'); ?>">Back to <?php echo get_post_type_archive_link('question'); ?></a>
```

Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Yes to all questions ;)

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with me when I wrote directly in the browser example: WordPress.Local/tasks, it works, but when I use get_post_type_archive_link like this to see what is the problem var_dump (get_post_type_archive_link('tasks ')) it return false

- i have added ( 'has_archive' => 'tasks') in register_post_type
- get_post_type_archive_link work fine with "post"

Answer (score 1):

In my Case, I simply update Permalink Structure

[image: Just Update Permalink Structure For page found issue]

[image: Creating custom Event type]

[image: Calling way]